Issues with different xscales but same domain values in D3 heatmap
I'm, pretty new to D3 and I am trying to build a heat-map in D3. It has different years. Each year has its own day scale(on x-axis) and year label should also be shown but shared month-scale(on y-axis).
My sample data structure is as follows -
    const data = [
     {
      year: 2023,
      data: [
      { month: "Jan", day: 1, value: 10 },
      { month: "Jan", day: 2, value: 20 },
      { month: "Jan", day: 3, value: 30 },
      { month: "Feb", day: 1, value: 10 },
      { month: "Feb", day: 2, value: 20 },
      { month: "Feb", day: 3, value: 30 },
      { month: "Mar", day: 1, value: 10 },
      { month: "Mar", day: 2, value: 20 },
      { month: "Mar", day: 3, value: 30 },

    ],
  },
  {
    group: 2024,
    data: [
      { month: "Jan", day: 1, value: 40 },
      { month: "Jan", day: 2, value: 30 },
     
      { month: "Feb", day: 1, value: 25 },
      { month: "Feb", day: 2, value: 20 },
      
      { month: "Mar", day: 1, value: 50 },
      { month: "Mar", day: 2, value: 23 },
     

    ],
  },
];

For example:

For year 2023 -> day scale domain is 1,2,3
For year 2024 -> day scale domain is 1,2
year scale below day scale is 2023,2024
Y-scale is Jan,Feb,Mar

Following is my code:
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const Heatmap = ({ data }) => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    const margin = { top: 40, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 80 };
    const width = 1500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const months = [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ];
    const totalDaySpace = width;
    const fixedDayWidth = totalDaySpace / 360;
    const boundsWidth = width - margin.right - margin.left;
    const boundsHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const yScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(months)
      .range([boundsHeight, margin.top])
      .padding(0.1);

    const nestedData = d3.group(data, (d) => d.year);

    const yearScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(Array.from(nestedData.keys()))
      .range([0, boundsWidth])
      .padding(0);
    // .padding((width - margin.left - margin.right) / (nestedData.size * 1.1));

    svg
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    const g = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0))
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "year-axis")
      .call(d3.axisTop(yearScale).tickSize(0))
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

    function dynamicDomain(daysPerYear, year) {
      console.log(totalDaySpace, fixedDayWidth, "****");
      // fixedDayWidth * daysPerYear.length
      const dayScale = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(daysPerYear.map((d) => d.day))
        .range([0, fixedDayWidth * daysPerYear.length])
        .padding(0);

      // console.log(daysPerYear.map((d) => dayScale(d.day)));
      // Render day axis for current year
      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "day-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${yearScale(year)}, 0)`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(dayScale).tickSize(0))
        .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());

      // Render heatmap rectangles for current year
      const rects = g
        .selectAll(`.day-rect-${year}`)
        .data(daysPerYear)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "day-rect")
        .attr("x", function (k) {
          return yearScale(k.year) + dayScale(k.day);
        })
        // .attr("x", (d) => yearScale(year) + dayScale(d.day))
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.month))
        .attr("width", dayScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
        .style("fill", (d) => getColor(d.value));
    }

    nestedData.forEach((yearData, year) => {
      dynamicDomain(yearData, year);
    });

    function getColor(value) {
      const colorScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range(["#fff", "#f00"]);
      return colorScale(value);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <svg
      ref={svgRef}
      width={1500}
      height={400}
      // style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
    />
  );
};

export default Heatmap;


I did show some gaps between each year in the heatmap - which is kind of placing multiple heatmaps side-by-side. But I'm struggling with width issues between years in getting them properly aligned. This is the output of how it looks now - Heatmap Output
